# Is there a way to add session variables to xsockets from another c# controller on another server instead of javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xsockets.net

I found JavaScript code that would allow me to persist information between sessions in the following article [Persistence between connections/sessions](http://xsockets.net/api/javascript/persistence-between-connectionssessions).

Is there a way of achieving this from the c# client api?

Also, is there a way to determine which session is tied to the person that initially created the chat session?